# Will paginate in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

```
<%= will_paginate @semails, :renderer => 'RemoteLinkRenderer' , :remote => {
:loading => 'loadingPanel.show()',:complete => 'loadingPanel.hide()'} %>
```

in rails2

how to convert this to rails3
This is the routes using for  rails 2 for semails

```
map.resources :users,
    :collection => {:uapload_avatars => :post, :aselect_friend => :get, :alist_friend => :get, :aist_moderator => :get},
    :member => {:anew_avatars => :get, :acreate_avatar => :post
     } do |user|

    user.resources :semails, :collection => { :sort => :get, :asave_draft =>  :post }

  end
```

how to convert this routes in rails 3 ?

I'm facing this error

will clicking the pagination link it just redirecting to the home page    is that routes issue or will paginate issue in rails 3

please help me to solve this issue

Comment: Are you using will_paginate 3.0? https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/tree/v3.0.pre2

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% about the spelling but the new routes for rails would approximate something like this:

```
  resources :user do
    collection do
      post "uapload_avatars"
      get "aselect_friend"
    end
    resources :semails do
      collection do
        get "sort"
        post "asave_draft"
      end
    end
  end
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html